# How to convert string with date and time AM/PM to 24 Hour mysql timestamp format

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am trying to insert date and time into mysql datetime field from a string having following **dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM** format:

```
20/10/2014 05:39 PM

20/10/2014 05:39 AM
```

I know MYSQL timestamp format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss  or **0000-00-00:00:00:00**

So if I do:

```
$s = substr("20/10/2014 05:39 PM", 0, 10);
$h = date("G:i", strtotime($s));
list($day, $month, $year, $hour, $minute) = split('[/ :]', "20/10/2014 05:39 PM"); 
echo $d1me = $year . '-' . $month. '-' .  $day . ' ' . $h;
```

I get `2014-10-20 19:00`

So I guess there is  a problem with date_default_timezone_set() function, How to solve this and get expected result?

```
20/10/2014 05:39 PM     ->   2014-10-20 17:39:00

20/10/2014 05:39 AM     ->   2014-10-20 05:39:00
```

How to do it?

Comment: You're overcomplicating this I think. You could just use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) natively in MySQL.

Comment: `select str_to_date('20/10/2014 05:39 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p')` results in `2014-10-20 17:39:00` And you can use that expression directly in your `INSERT`'s `VALUES()` list.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think that would be the best answer/solution!

Comment: `strtotime()` only works with a very narrow set of pre-defined date/time formats, and the interpretation is frequently not what you might expect. You're much better off with functions that allow you to unambiguously define the input format, such as MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and PHP's [`date_create_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL already knows how to parse many different types of date strings natively, using the [`STR_TO_DATE()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in combination with format strings used by [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

So, I would not involve PHP in this process at all, and instead allow MySQL to parse the input itself.

The format string you need to use is `%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p`, where the `%p` represents `AM/PM`.

You can use the entire expression right in your `INSERT` statement, passing the strings directly from PHP assuming you have validated their format already.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (timestamp_column) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('20/10/2014 05:39 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p'));
```

...will correctly insert the `DATETIME` value `2014-10-20 17:39:00` into your table.

If you really prefer to do it in PHP first, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (PHP 5.3+) using the format string `'d/m/Y H:i A'`

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', '20/10/2014 05:39 PM');
var_dump($d);

class DateTime#2 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "2014-10-20 17:39:00.000000"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(15) "America/Chicago"
```

To get a MySQL formatted date back out of it,

```
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// 2014-10-20 17:39:00
```

If you are in the *deeply unfortunate* situation of having a PHP version older than 5.3, you can achieve similar results with [`strptime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) but you'll need to assemble its array output into MySQL's string format.

Comment: Didn't know about that function, very cool! Also that it recognize AM and PM.

Comment: And then to re-jigger it into a MySQL date string: `$d->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')`

Comment: Doing php solution I get  `Message: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string` How to solve it?

Comment: @cMinor How exactly are you using it? You need to call `$d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s)` to get a different string back out in MySQL's format, but the `$d->date` property happens to be in a usable format too.

Comment: Actually, `$d->date` is probably not useful. Use `$d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` Example http://codepad.viper-7.com/p5Rong

Comment: I get error when usin `$d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` : `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object`

Comment: @cMinor `$d` is the `DateTime` object created with `$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', '20/10/2014 05:39 PM');`  You must create it first, then call `format()` on it.

Comment: @cMinor You can also do it as a one-liner if you only need the value once and won't reuse the object, by chaining the methods: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', '20/10/2014 05:39 PM')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $input = "20/10/2014 05:39 AM";  //20/10/2014 05:39 PM

    list($day, $month, $year, $hour, $minute, $dayType) = preg_split('/[\/\s:]+/', $input); 
    echo $d1me = $year . '-' . $month. '-' .  $day . ' ' . ($dayType == "PM"?$hour+12: $hour) . ":" . $minute . ":00";

?>
```

Output:

```
2014-10-20 05:39:00  //2014-10-20 17:39:00
```

Comment: Why downvote? It works. Maybe it's not the best answer, but there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I agree, that's kind of harsh

Comment: Are you sure you fully validated the input? What if someone entered 99 as hours? or 19 PM? Library function can be expected to automatically handle for you many tricky cases you didn't even imagine yet. That's why as a general rule it's *much* better to use library functions when possible, instead of ad hoc hand-rolled attempts.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the following code. It's easier to understand:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("20/10/2014 05:39 PM"));
```

Comment: Why had anyone marked this down? It's a far easier solution than anything proposed above and I believe it to be equally performant, and it works in php version back to I don't remember when.

Answer (score 1):

This is the better way if you are using php

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('20/10/2014 05:39 PM'));
```

Answer (score -1):

> echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("20-10-2014 05:39 PM"));

Use above code - but keep in mind you have "-" in place of "/" in input date.